# Images doesnt resize in flexbox

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, responsive

I have this

```
.parentcontainer
{
background-color: black;
max-width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: space-around;


}

.aside
{
display:flex;
flex: 30%;

flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
justify-content: flex-start;
align-items: stretch;



}
.content
{

background-color: blue;
flex: 70%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
align-content: flex-start;
max-height:800px;


}

.content img
{
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

when I resize the browser the imgs of the .content doesnt resize and I need to do a horizontal scroll. How can I do for resizing the images? and the child container doesnt get bigger than the parent container. thanks.

EDIT: now I change .content to columns, and mas height to 800px. I want the articles of the .content go down,and when they reach 800px, make another column. the problem stays, the articles of .content goes outside the parent box instead or resize...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.content img{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto
}
```

Comment: Do you have demo on some testing url? Or can you specify your problem on jsfiddle.net? Thanks